# SCardGetStatusChange First-chance exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, winscard

I'm using following code in a thread:

```
SCardGetStatusChange(hContext, timeout, rgReaderStates_t, nbReaders);
```

where:

```
SCARDCONTEXT hContext;
DWORD timeout; 
SCARD_READERSTATE *rgReaderStates_t = NULL; 
DWORD nbReaders;
```

Everything works correctly, but this function generate a lot of error:

> First-chance exception at 0x7510C42D in app.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x05A0F3A8.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Windows-7 64bit.

Please help.
thanks!